# Programmatically trigger flow and send properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, flow, react

I want to manually trigger an external flow from my SPFx project, and at the same time send values to the flow.

In flow, I have my request body:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "emailaddress": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "id": {
        "type": "number"
    },
},
"required": [
    "emailaddress",
    "id"
]
 }
```

I have the unique URL/Path to my flow.

But how do I connect to flow (via this path, or some other possible way) and at the same time send data to it?

I am using JavaScript/react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpClient REST` call in your SPFx web part to **POST** the properties to unique URL/Path to your flow.

You can find the detailed article on how to run a Microsoft Flow from a SharePoint Framework (SPFx) web part in below link:

[How To: Run a Microsoft Flow from a SharePoint Framework (SPFx) web part](http://toddbaginski.com/blog/how-to-run-a-microsoft-flow-from-a-sharepoint-framework-spfx-web-part/).

Also, below is the similar example (Not in SPFx) to trigger Microsoft Flow with a button click using `AJAX Call`. This will help you to understand how to pass the properties to Microsoft flow:

[Trigger A Microsoft Flow With A Button Click On SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/trigger-a-microsoft-flow-with-a-button-click-on-sharepoint-online/).